# How to detect application préference changes

Tags: iphone, preferences

I created a Settings.bundle in my app where the user can change some properties like font size. It works.

But when I leave my App, and I change my setting, I don't know how I can get notified of the change. 
For the moment, I create a function call each time a view is loaded that check for app settings. 
But I wonder if there is an other and proper way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, or an equivalent location, to check your `NSUserDefaults` values, or just read them in a `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` method.

While there is no multi-tasking, this is more than adequate.  On MacOS X Cocoa we use KVO and bindings to check for changes during the execution of an application; no doubt something similar will work for 4.0 if required.

Comment: I used to check setting values in the application:didFinishLaunching, but the problem is that when the user leave the app, change the value of font size (for exemple), and come back to my app, the application:didFinishLaunching function is not callback, so change isn't taked into account.

Comment: It is always called on launch.  You can't get from Settings to your app without launching it in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Like you said Paul, for 4.0 sdk version, there is something similar and I found it in "UIApplicationDelegate protocol". 
Thank you for helping me. ;)